# React Native Local Database Sync with Mysql

Tags: mysql, react-native, sqlite, realm

Is possible to Offline sqlLite saved data send or sync with live ***MySQL database in server side*** ?

Comment: any solution for this. still looking but found nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own solution to this scenario.
I try to build up React Native mobile app working with Laravel backend(PHP) and my app working online and offline both. So my mobile app using Realm (of MongoDB) to app db and MySQL in severe side (Laravel). I create the flag field in both dbs to know that row is sync or not and i develop the function to check that flag field and sync to both db and update flag field as my wish. You can try this with SQLite or any other mobile db.
Realm:https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to do so is to use WatermelonDB.

See: https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB

It provides a syncing option from which you can automatically sync your database with the backend. It uses SQlite on it back. For synchronisation see:

https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Advanced/Sync.html